# Generate serial numbers and barcodes as per logic defined based on the count mention in certain cell

Tags: excel, vba

I need to generate lot numbers for my products and since my software doesn't auto generate them, I have defined a logic in Excel for the same. It is quite basic and combines data in 2 or more cells to create a unique code.

To be more specific, I shall introduce our operations to you. We have a few collection centers for our products and we require them to apply lot number labels onto their bags of coffee before transferring it to our main warehouse. I have created an excel sheet in which I enter the current date in one cell and select the name of the center in another which then generates a lot number for the same. For example, cell A1 has today's date and A2 has center 'MBR' selected. The formula in cell C2 `=IF(A2="MBR","MB:"&TEXT(A1,"YYYYMMDD")&"-001",IF(A2="MAY","AY:"&TEXT(A1,"YYYYMMDD")&"-001",IF(A2="MZM","MM:"&TEXT(A1,"YYYYMMDD")&"-001","")))` shall give me a result as **MB:20171010-001**

Now comes the tricky part. I want to mention in cell A3 the number of lots to be generated. For example, if I say I want 10 labels, then the formula should give me 10 labels from "-001" to "-010." If possible, it could start with the number which I would define in possibly cell A4 and then give me the sequence as required.

Lastly, I use this info to generate barcodes using an add-on in excel which I downloaded from the internet which converts the text into barcodes and then I can print them. I have tried barcode fonts but they don't work at all. If you have another alternative to this where I could generate sequential lot numbers based on the logic defined and create barcodes for the same, please share it with me. If not, please give me a formula which will work with excel.

Answer (score 0):

[image]
Enter your data in columns A - C, run the bit of sample code below, result is in column D. You can modify the code to suit your needs but here is a start for you:

```
Public Sub RunTags()

Dim oWS             As Worksheet
Dim lRow            As Long
Dim lNextTagRow     As Long

    Set oWS = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    lRow = 2
    lNextTagRow = 2
    Do Until oWS.Range("A" & lRow) = ""
        Select Case oWS.Range("A" & lRow)
            Case "MBR"
                PrintTags oWS, lNextTagRow, "MB:", oWS.Range("B" & lRow), oWS.Range("C" & lRow)
            Case "MAY"
                PrintTags oWS, lNextTagRow, "MA:", oWS.Range("B" & lRow), oWS.Range("C" & lRow)
            Case "MZM"
                PrintTags oWS, lNextTagRow, "MZ:", oWS.Range("B" & lRow), oWS.Range("C" & lRow)
        End Select
        lRow = lRow + 1
    Loop
End Sub
```

.

```
Private Sub PrintTags(ByRef oWS As Worksheet, ByRef lTagRowStart As Long, sPrefix As String, lQty As Long, lStart As Long)
    Dim x           As Long
    Dim dtNow       As Date

    dtNow = Now()
    For x = lStart To lStart + lQty - 1
        oWS.Range("D" & lTagRowStart) = sPrefix & Format(dtNow, "YYYYMMDD") & "-" & Format(x, "000")
        lTagRowStart = lTagRowStart + 1
    Next x
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks, but I'm a little new to this code thing. Could you please explain in a little more detail on how and where to enter it?

Comment: Ok, I tried to see it I could make it work so I created a new workbook and copied the data as you have shown then right clicked on the sheet and selected "view code" and in the open window, I just pasted what you shared. Then I clicked on "save" and then the small "play" button. Now my screen is showing me an error saying, "Compile error: Sub or function not defined." Nothing has happened.

Please explain what has to be done next and also explain what should happen. I'm blank when it comes to coding.

Thanks.

Comment: Im on my phone so i xant see it but try this: alt-f11 to open the VBA window. Insert a module (not a class module). Copy and past both of the procedures above into the module. Then click anywhere inside of the Public procedure and click the Play arrow

Comment: Ok, I got it. Its pretty neat. However, its incomplete. In order for me to start using it on a daily basis, its needs to match my requirement completely.

I need to printout 3 copies of a single lot number and give it to the manager. 2 copies shall go with the bag and one would be passed on to accounts. I need 3 fields where I could select the center, the number of copies to be printed and the date. After which, the spreadsheet should populate the range in a predefined label sheet which shall be printed, cut and distributed to the centers.

Can this be worked out?

Comment: I could work all of that out for you, but you should be able to build on what I provided to complete your task.

Comment: Ok, so now the requirements have changed slightly. We have decided to move to Google Sheets so that we can manage everything in one place and also be able to modify it offline. Would you be having any expertise in that? If you do, I have a complete workflow ready so that you can give a all-in-one solution.

Comment: Please check out my post on this google product forms
https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/7RWMR1H0jEE;context-place=mydiscussions